# MYSQL - Select values in table A where all the corresponding values in table B have a specific values

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, `orders` and `ordered_products`.

```
ORDERS
|ORDERS_ID|CUSTOMER NAME|...
|1        |PIPPO        |...
|2        |PLUTO        |...

ORDERED PRODUCTS
|ORDERED_ID|ORDERS_ID|PRODUCT  |PRODUCT_TYPE|...
|1         |1        |ProdottoA| 1          |...
|2         |1        |ProdottoB| 2          |...
|3         |1        |ProdottoC| 1          |...
|4         |2        |ProdottoD| 2          |...
```

I need two queries, the first to select all orders that have **at least** one product of type 1, the second to select all orders that have ALL products of type 1.

For the first one i have solved with the following query:

```
select distinct orders_id from ORDERS o left join ORDERED_PRODUCTS op on (o.orders_id=op.orders_id) where op.product_type = '1'
```

But I can't find a solution for the second query.

---

Solution found! I used:

```
select distinct orders_id from ORDERS o left join ORDERED_PRODUCTS op on (o.orders_id=op.orders_id) 
where
(select count(ordered_id) from ordered_products op where op.orders_id = o.orders_id)
=
(select count(ordered_id) from ordered_products op where op.orders_id = o.orders_id and op.orders_products_categorizzazione='1')
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but this should work :

```
select orders_id
from orders
where 
  ( 
  select count(distinct product)
    from ordered_products
    where ordered_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
    and ordered_products.product_type = 1
  )
  =
  (
  select count(distinct product)
    from ordered_products
    where ordered_products.product_type = 1
  );
```

What it does :

- Count all distinct products of type 1 in the current order
- Count all distinct products of type 1 within all orders
- Compare results

It's far from optimized and there probably are better methods, but it does the work and it's easily understandable.

PS : If you have the choice of the database structure, I'd go for having a different table for products themselves. Fits better in UML specifications, less redundancy, better indexing.

Answer (score 0):

First query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE Exists (select null
              from ordered_products
              where
                orders.orders_id = ordered_products.orders_id
                and product_type=1)
```

And the second one:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE
  Orders_id in (select orders_id
                from ordered_products
                where ordered_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
                group by orders_id
                having sum(if(product_type=1,1,0))=count(*))
```